# Example of a 3-dimensional manifold with toroidal boundary, which is not a solid torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I am looking for an example of a $3$-dimensional compact and orientable topological manifold $\mathcal{M}$ with boundary, such that $\partial\mathcal{M}$ is homeomorphic to a $2$-torus $T^{2}=S^{1}\times S^{1}$, but such that $\mathcal{M}$ is not homeomorphic to the solid torus $\overline{T}^{2}:=S^{1}\times\overline{D}$, where $\overline{D}$ denotes the closed disk (=closed $2$-ball).

This is basically a similar question as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293658/is-every-orientable-and-compact-3-dimensional-with-spherical-boundary-and-eule), which I've created some days ago. In this post I asked for manifolds, with spherical boundary, which are not homeomorphic to a $3$-ball. As explained by Moishe Kohan in this post, a general procedure to built them is to consider an arbitrary closed orientable $3$-manifold (which is not equivalent to $S^{3}$), from which we "cut out" the interior of a regular $3$-ball. Is there a similar procedure which works for the torus case?

I already know from the well-known theorem $\chi(\mathcal{M})=\frac{1}{2}\chi(\partial\mathcal{M})$ for odd-dimensional compact manifolds that every manifold $\mathcal{M}$ with toroidal boundary has to have $\chi(\mathcal{M})=0$. So, whenever someone knows an example of a $3$-dimensional compact and orientable manifold with a single boundary component, whose Euler-characterisitc is zero, then we would be done.

Comment: Take a solid torus and connect sum with a closed 3 manifold that isn't a sphere.

Comment: @ConnorMalin thanks for the comment, I think this is what I am looking for. I am only familiar with the connected sum of two closed manifold. Could you elaborate a little bit how the connected sum of a closed manifold with a manifold with boundary is defined?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the same procedure works for the torus case: take an arbitrary closed orientable 3-manifold from which we "cut out" the interior of an embedded regular solid torus.

In this situation there is no need to rule out $S^3$. In fact $S^3$ gives us gobs of beautiful examples closely related to [knot complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_complement): in fact what this construction shows is that every knot complement is the interior of a 3-manifold with torus boundary.

Comment: I'd just like to add that a sufficient (but not necessary) condition is that, if after removing the solid torus, the resulting manifold $M$ is such that the induced map $\pi_1(\partial M)\to\pi_1(M)$ is injective.  In this case, $M$ is definitely not a solid torus (this follows from the loop theorem).  If this map is not injective, then $M$ is actually a connect sum with a solid torus.